# Excel, check if a column has the same amount of characters for each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like to add a check to my worksheet in Excel, to test if entries in a column have the same total number of characters. I know how to do it for two cells where I can simply use `=IF(EXACT(LEN(A1),LEN(A2)),"Match","No Match")` but what if I have a lot of cells to test against each other?

Example:

[image: example image]

Comment: Add a new column B with formula `B1 = LEN(A1)` then use the fact that if all len are the same using standard deviation on the B column (or something like that)

Comment: I am unsure how to do the second part? Could you please help me out with the formula...

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper column `B` with `=LEN(A1)`, etc in each row, then a check cell in say `C1` with `=STDEV.P(B:B)=0`. This will show `TRUE` if all entries in column `A` are the same length and `FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula (entered by holding down `ctrl` + `shift` while hitting `enter`):

```
=IF(AND(LEN(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A)))/LEN($A$1)=1),"Match","No Match")
```

or this normally entered formula:

```
=IF(AND(MMULT(LEN(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A))),1/LEN($A$1))=1),"Match","No Match")
```

You could also use the Std Dev calculation, as suggested by others, in an array (CSE) formula so as to avoid the helper column:

```
=IF(STDEV.P(LEN(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A)))),"No Match","Match")
```